# Case Statement to determine if value in column is unique

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out if an 'Activity_ID' is unique for each 'Provider', and ideally I would like to do this via a Case Statement.

If I write a case statement to show you how I would like to approach this, then it would perhaps make more sense;

```
 CASE WHEN Concat (Activity_ID,Provider) IS **UNIQUE/DISTINCT** THEN 'Yes'
   ELSE 'No'
   END 'Unique_Flag'

   --Concat has been used as it is possible for a Provider to have an Activity_ID
     which is also used by another provider, however there is no connection and i am 
     only interested in if an Activity_ID is unique for an indvidual provider
```

I would like the desired outcome to be something like below. I believe I am close and just need to replace **UNIQUE/DISTINCT** in the above with the appropriate command

```
Provider       Activity_ID    Unique_Flag
ProvA              11           Yes
ProvA              22           No
ProvA              22           No
ProvA              33           Yes
ProvA              44           Yes  
ProvA              55           Yes
ProvB              55           No
ProvB              55           No
```

Comment: You can do it for example using (select count(*) from thesametable) > 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Provider, Activity_ID) > 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Unique' END, *
FROM ...
```

Using the OVER clause like this will run the aggregate across different windows of data, thereby letting you group by those two columns without destroying the rest of the set.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. You could use a derived table for example:

```
    --Sample Table and Data
    DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
        Provider VARCHAR(5),
        Activity_ID TINYINT
    )

    INSERT INTO @table 
    VALUES
    ('ProvA',11),
    ('ProvA',22),
    ('ProvA',22),
    ('ProvA',33),
    ('ProvA',44),
    ('ProvA',55),
    ('ProvB',55),
    ('ProvB',55)

    -- Your desired query using a derived table
    SELECT  t.Provider, t.Activity_ID,
            CASE WHEN t2.Cnt = 1 
                THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
            END AS Unique_Flag
    FROM    @table t
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT Provider, Activity_ID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
            FROM    @table
            GROUP BY Provider,Activity_ID) t2 
                ON t.Provider = t2.Provider
                AND t.Activity_ID = t2.Activity_ID
```